# Maven Multi Module execution point

Tags: maven, maven-2, maven-3, m2eclipse

I want to work with Maven multi module wich is formed of 4 modules : Domain module , DAL module, service module and web module. All of these modules have a parent project. the problem is that I don't know where the execution point is ? Shall I run it from the Web Module ? or from the parent maven project ? and if I run it from the parent project, the packaging of the parent project is 'POM' and not 'WAR' ? Shall change it ? Please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to run it from the parent module if you have a structure like this:

```
root
  +-- pom.xml
       +--- domain
       !     +-- pom.xml 
       +--- dal
       !     +-- pom.xml 
       +--- service
       !     +-- pom.xml 
       +--- web
             +-- pom.xml
```

which means to go into the **root** directory and do things like **mvn clean** or **mvn package**.

And you should **NOT** change the packaging of the root project.